# Pure Javascript FlashPlayer: why can't I make it work?

Tags: javascript, flash, svg

There are some demos here:
http://paulirish.com/work/gordon/demos/

I downloaded blue.html as well as blue.swf on my local pc. But opening it I can't make it work.

Why ?

Comment: Can you upload the html file, .swf file and JS file somewhere so we can check it against the Demonstration ?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it on your local PC using `file://` URL's, I'll bet a beer it's not working due to browser security restrictions. You should be getting warnings in Firefox's error console if that's the case.

You'd then need to test it on a web server, or set up a local web server accessible through `http://localhost`.

Comment: Can you add some details what doesn't work? Maybe post a live URL?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are trying to play an incompatible .swf file. According to its gitHub page, the player can not render any .swfs over version 2.

A SWF Tag support table is on Github here,

http://wiki.github.com/tobeytailor/gordon/swf-tag-support-table/

Comment: I downloaded the same swf file the demo is using